# Deselecting layers in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro

I can't figure out how to batch deselect layers in ArcGIS Pro. I have added ~200 images to a project map, and now want to deselect without deleting all of them because I applied a common symbology. This was super easy in ArcMap, could select and right click, but that doesn't seem like an option in ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to uncheck (turn off all) layers listed in the Contents at once, you can hold Control and click the checkbox. That will turn them all off. If you want to turn off all but keep one layer on, you can hold Alt and click the layer of interest to turn the rest off. You can read more about these ArcGIS Pro [shortcuts](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/map-authoring/contents-pane-shortcuts.htm).

If you have bunch of items selected on the map and you want to unselect them, there are a number of options. Here is some more information on ArcGIS Pro about [selecting features](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/select-features-interactively.htm) and more on [working with selected features](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/work-with-selected-features.htm) (includes clearing a selection). That said, there is also a clear selection button that looks the same as it does in ArcMap.

[image: ArcGIS Pro Clear Selection Button]